# Improving join queries performance with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2012

We want to improve performance of our join queries, and the index is on a column of `nvarchar(1000)`.

Is using an index on another data type, for example `bigint` (by adding additional column and fill it using some hash map function on the original column) increase performance?

Will changing the index to `nvarchar(200)` instead of `nvarchar(1000)` increase performance (assuming the longest value can be 200 chars)?

Comment: Could you provide you DB structure with your query>>

Comment: I just want to get a principal answer, is index on number is better than index on chars? is index on navchar(1000) is better than index on navchar(200) when the values are the same and never exceeds 200 chars?

Comment: if the number is same big as that navchar, it will have same performance. Navchar(200)' index will have better performance then...read my answer :)

Comment: Or try to specify question.

Comment: `nvarchar(1000)` is more than 900 bytes - so you **cannot** index this column. So changing it to `nvarchar(200)` can help, since you would be able to index this column. And an index on a foreign key column is usually beneficial for performance

Answer (score 0):

The performance of index is in dependence of amount row and size of indexed column.

Yes, adding the additional column with hashmap, using and indexing, that could a little bit increase performance of SQL queries, because indexies will be smaller and sql will faster operate with them in memory. But you will have to calculate hashmaps somewhere else, so the final performance of app wouldn't be bigger. There is one more problem the hashmap with big amount of data are working unpredictable.(There can be 1 hashmap for n value of navchar). So I would finally said, it isn't good idea.

Changing navchar(1000) to navchar(200) sounds little bit better. Indexies will be smaller, faster, insert of new value will be faster too and what is most important, it will be stable. But performance difference wouldn't be so glorious.

Comment: `nvarchar(1000)` **cannot** be used as an index column, since it surpasses the 900 bytes maximum for an index entry.

Comment: There hasn't been told, what kind of sql server he uses. How would you know then?

Comment: ***ALL*** versions of SQL Server (up to and including 2016) have this 900 byte limit on index entries

Comment: @marc_s actually it can be used, but when you'll be creating an indice, it will warn that index might exceed and updates/inserts will fail in the future. If currently there's no value longer than (450), index should work.

Comment: What about MySQL server?